# $g = \chi_{E}$ where $E = \{(x, t): t \ge f(x)\}$, a function in two variables, is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, characteristic-functions, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Equip $[0, \infty)$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $f: X \to [0, \infty)$ be a measurable function. Define $g: X \times [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ by

$g(x, t) = 1$ if $t \ge f(x)$

$g(x, t) = 0$ if $t < f(x)$

I want to show that $g$ is measurable.

It is clear that $g = \chi_{E}$ where $E = \{(x, t): t \ge f(x)\}$. So it suffices to prove that $E$ is measurable under the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Fix $t \ge 0$. Define $E_t = \{(x, t): x \in f^{-1}(-\infty, t)\}$. Then $E = \cup_{t \in [0, \infty)}E_t$.

Each $E_t$ is measurable as singletons are measurable in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and the preimage of $f$ is measurable. The cartesian product of measurable sets is measurable. However, where this fails is that I am taking an uncountable union, which does not necessarily preserve measurability. I am thinking it is perhaps $\sigma$-finiteness of $X$ that may help here, but I don't know how.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: $g=\mathbb 1_{[0,\infty)}\circ h\circ j$ where $j(x,t)=(f(x),t)$ and $h(x,y)=y-x$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a direct proof? We haven't learned that measurability is preserved under compositions yet, though I take it this means $\sigma$-finiteness is not necessary

Comment: There are several equivalent definitions of Borel measurability. One that works very well for questions like this is that the inverse image of a Borel set is a Borel set. Given that, it's immediate that Borel measurability is preserved under compositions.